# Trying to connect bose quietcomfort 35 headset over bluetooth on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez

There is another question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292189/pairing-bose-qc-35-over-bluetooth-on-fedora), but i followed those instructions and it still didn't work.

Here is the systemctl status

```
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: Bluetooth daemon 5.42
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: Starting SDP server
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: Bluetooth management interface 1.12 initialized
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Oct 06 10:02:38 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
Oct 06 10:03:00 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 04:52:C7:0E:7F:12: Protocol not available
Oct 06 10:06:20 TRAYUSH bluetoothd[376]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 04:52:C7:0E:7F:12: Protocol not available
```

Here are the contents of /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
[General]
ControllerMode=bredr
```

And the contents of /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf

```
[General]
Enable=Source,Sink,Headset,Gateway,Control,Socket,Media
```

Here is what happens when I try to connect via bluetoothctl

```
[trash@TRAYUSH ~]$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 98:58:8A:07:14:FC TRAYUSH [default]
[NEW] Device 04:52:C7:0E:7F:12 QC35
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect 04:52:C7:0E:7F:12
```

Here is the relevant information from /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Ninja Edit: Pulseaudio-bluetooth IS installed.

Comment: Have the same problem with both of my Linux machines (with very different Bluetooth controllers), no solutions in sight. Tried all kinds of permutations of all the above options.

Comment: Alex Balashov, it works on fedora 25, so you should maybe try that.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be relevant to your case, but I had the same issue on Arch Linux with bluez 5.41. I kept getting a connection failure when trying to pair.

In my case, after exhausting the possibility that my relatively bleeding-edge motherboard's built-in Bluetooth controller was simply not supported, I eventually discovered that the headphones pair just fine—as long as they are located no more than an inch or two from the chassis. :-) I cannot say quite why that is, although the possibility that the chassis interferes physically.

Regardless, my solution was to get an external USB Bluetooth adaptor, after which things work swimmingly.