# How to detect Bluetooth X-Box controller?

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

tl;dr: Why does Linux not detect my Bluetooth X-Box controller?

My system:

- New X-Box model 1914 controller with original firmware and new batteries.
- Up-to-date Arch Linux with vanilla kernel:

  ```
  $ uname --kernel-name --kernel-release --kernel-version --machine --operating-system
  Linux 5.10.9-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 19 Jan 2021 22:06:06 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- Targus-branded Broadcom USB Bluetooth dongle:

  ```
  $ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
  ```

What I've done:

1. Installed latest xpadneo driver as of 2021-01-24:

   ```
   $ pacman --query xpadneo-dkms-git 
   xpadneo-dkms-git 0.9.r16.g2850d4d-1
   ```
2. Installed latest firmware for the Bluetooth dongle:

   ```
   $ pacman --query broadcom-bt-firmware-git 
   broadcom-bt-firmware-git 12.0.1.1105_p3.r0.g68a7a8a-1
   ```
3. Disabled Enhanced ReTransmission Mode:

   ```
   $ cat /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm
   Y
   ```
4. Rebooted, after which `dmesg` showed that the firmware was updated:

   ```
   $ sudo dmesg --notime | grep BCM20702A
   Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1764
   Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd' Patch
   Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1764
   ```
5. Manually loaded the xpadneo kernel driver:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe xpad
   $ lsmod |grep xpad
   xpad                   40960  0
   ff_memless             20480  1 xpad
   ```
6. Powered on the X-Box controller and enabled Bluetooth discovery mode (the "X" icon on the controller is blinking more quickly than when it powered on).
7. Did a Bluetooth scan & device listing with `bluetoothctl`.

What I was expecting to happen: The controller should show up in the device listing after scanning for a while.

What actually happened: The controller does not show up, even though three other devices do show up.

The same goes for the GNOME Bluetooth setting dialogue: other devices show up, but not the X-Box controller.

[xpadneo crosspost](https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo/issues/93#issuecomment-766271856)

---

Also tried:

1. Verified that [SDL 2.0.14 is installed](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/post/248607):

   ```
   $ pacman --query sdl2
   sdl2 2.0.14-1
   ```
2. Setting [`Privacy = device` in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/post/248966) and restarting the bluetooth service.
3. Manually loaded hid-xpadneo kernel module:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe hid-xpadneo
   $ lsmod |grep xpad
   xpad                   40960  0
   hid_xpadneo            24576  0
   ff_memless             20480  2 xpad,hid_xpadneo
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was `ControllerMode = bredr` in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf, which I had [set](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/-/commit/8ce399aaaa8771daf3419dbb28de7453f00a3ad3) to [work around an unrelated Bluetooth issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293967/3645).